# can you please explain for d in range(arr-1,0,-1) (what are 0 and -1)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

what are these arguments in loop ? (0 and -1)

Comment: Programming funcitons are usually documented. especially basic functions - google-ing them will help you understand them. Here is the link to the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range  - just printing out what it does should help you understand it - simply provide it with some data:  `print(range(20,0,-1))` f.e.

Answer (score 0):

range(x,y,z)

x = start (where you want the range to start)

y = stop  (The stopping point which is not inclusive)

z = step  (The amount to step over i.e -1 means to step backwards)